# How can i use Remote Attribute in Mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes

I developing business application in ASP MVC 5. I was trying to use `Remote` attribute but its not working.

#### Metadata class - where i put attribute

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Departmanmetadata))]
    public partial class DepartmanTable
    {

    }
    public class Departmanmetadata
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Deparman No")]
        public int DepartmanID { get; set; }



        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan boş bırakılamaz!")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Lütfen 2 ile 50 karakter arasında veri giriniz!")]
        [DisplayName("Departman Adı")]
        [Remote("IsNameAvaible", "Departman", ErrorMessage = "Sistemde zaten var!")]
        public string DepartmanName { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Controller

```
 public JsonResult IsNameAvaible(string name)
        {
            return Json(!db.DepartmanTable.Any(a => a.DepartmanName == name), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

#### View

```
<link href="~/css/eklemeler.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>DEPARTMAN</h2>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Departman</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <strong>Departman Add</strong>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
</div>
<br />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Departman Add</h5>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a class="collapse-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="close-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="~/Departman/Create" novalidate>
                         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="item form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmanName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmanName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" } })<span class="fa fa-long-arrow-up form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmanName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Ekle" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
                                    <i class="fa fa-share fa-2x"></i> @Html.ActionLink("Geri Dön!", "Index")
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Create button doesn't working.
I think Scripts is the problem. Here the scripts.

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: its look like button should do post but its not clear from controller code, can you provide more detail how to repro error and more code of controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you apply the attribute to is named `DepartmanName` and generates the following html

```
<input type="text" name="DepartmanName" ..... />
```

which means you controller method must have a matching parameter. Change it to

```
public JsonResult IsNameAvaible(string departmanName)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yes it will!. And if its not then you have something else you have not shown us that is causing the problem. And here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9ZLvV) I created for another user to prove it works.

Comment: i found correct answer.I am sorry, i didn't write.  the reason of error was wrong order of javascript.

Comment: The code in your question shows the scripts in the correct order. The reason it does not work is as I stated in my answer - the name of the parameter is wrong

Comment: i didn't try your answer but i changed order of javascript no problem.Thank you for your concern.